# refactor helper for default state for rails select with enums

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I've created a helper method that is essentially used to get the default state of an select:

```
<%= select_tag "question_main_frequency",
          options_for_frequency_state(frequency_segment(question)), { class: 'form-control' } %>
```

The helper method I've created to get the default state looks like this:

```
  def frequency_segment(question)
    return false if question.id.nil?
    question = Question.find(question.id)
    if question.weekly?
      'weekly'
    elsif question.odd_weeks? || question.even_weeks?
      'Biweekly'
    elsif question.start_of_month? || question.end_of_month?
      'Monthly'
    elsif question.start_of_quarter? || question.end_of_quarter?
      'Quarterly'
    end
  end
```

The reason why I need this is because that form populates a new select form with the methods you see in the helper. So if they select 'biweekly' then `question.odd_weeks` and `question.even_weeks`appear as two options.

and you don't have to be a genius to see that this isn't exactly beautiful. It's also causing:

```
Perceived complexity for frequency_segment is too high. [10/7]
Method has too many lines. [11/10]
Cyclomatic complexity for frequency_segment is too high.[9/6]
```

on rubocop. The thing is I'm not entirely sure how to refactor this. The Question methods are enum, set up like this:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum frequency: { weekly: 0, odd_weeks: 1, even_weeks: 2,
                    start_of_month: 3, end_of_month: 4,
                    start_of_quarter: 5, end_of_quarter: 6 }
```

any ideas on how I can refactor this?

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, try to write a title that summarizes what your code does, not what you want to get out of a review. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/41243) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: @BCdotWEB thanks for good pointers! I've gone ahead and updated my answer, hopefully this is more useful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if there's a good way to do this, since your translation isn't 1:1. E.g. your enum differentiates between odd weeks and even weeks, but your helper doesn't.

So you have to do some sort of work to collapse 7 states into 4 options.

If you're already using I18n to do translation, you might be able to put the strings in there, e.g.:

```
question:
  frequency:
    - weekly
    - biweekly
    - biweekly
    - monthly
    - monthly
    - quarterly
    - quarterly
```

and the use the standard Rails I18n helpers to fetch the right string. But that's not too pretty either, and really only hides the problem from Rubocop. It's also a more implicit connection, and more error-prone, so, yeah, you probably shouldn't go down this road.

Frankly, I wouldn't bother *too* much about Rubocop's opinion about method length or cyclomatic complexity in this case. *But...*

But there's weird stuff going on too:

- You're passing in a `question` and checking its `id`. But it's not a real `Question` record? Because you immediately go and fetch one from the database. So what are you passing in that's called `question`, has an `id`, but isn't actually a `Question`?
- You're also overwriting the argument variable with the record you fetch, which is not a great idea. Now you have a `question` that's apparently not really a `Question`, but then maybe it becomes a `question` that is actually a `Question`. Confused? Me too.
- Oh, and are you sure you're going to find something when you call `find(id)`? If not, you'll get a 404 `RecordNotFound` error. It might be completely intentional to let that happen, but to have the page break due to a helper method is perhaps a little icky.
- Why return `false`? If anything, you should return `nil`. Ideally, you return a string, but the "opposite" of a string isn't `false` - at best it's `nil`. And actually, your method *could* conceivably return `nil` already, since you don't have an `else` branch in your logic. If, for whatever reason, none of the `if/elsif` conditions are true, your method will return `nil`.

Anyway, without worrying about the `question` vs `question` thing and possible exceptions being thrown, I'd suggest at least using a `case` statement instead of a lot of `elsif`s:

```
case
when question.weekly?
  'Weekly'
when question.odd_weeks?, question.even_weeks?
  'Biweekly'
when question.start_of_month?, question.end_of_month?
  'Monthly'
when question.start_of_quarter?, question.end_of_quarter?
  'Quarterly'
else
  nil
end
```

Oh, and I capitalized "Weekly" to match the other strings.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the good reply, the question I get is in-fact a real Question record. I see now that I am over-writing it. On your note about recordnotfound I felt that I avoided that by returning false if it's not present. Is that not optimal, if so how would you do it taking this update into account?

Comment: @SebastianJenningsAlmnes Well, if the point is that you want to reload the record to make sure it's up to date, then, well, there's the `reload` method. As for the id check, I'd actually forgotten it was there. It should protect you... however: The question may have been deleted from the database since you got that ID. It's unlikely, but if those question records are manipulated elsewhere it _might_ happen. If you're sure they're there, then ok, but you are doing a check leading me to think you're not sure about that.

Comment: You can test `question.frequency` in the case statement - it returns the string representation of the value (e.g. `"odd_weeks"`)

Comment: @Spike True, but I'd rather have Ruby raise a `NoMethodError` if I've misspelled, `.odd_weks?` (sic), than silently hit the `else` case because I've misspelled the same thing in a string.